# How to access the method of other Function component functionality in different component in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I use the countdown timer reactjs package. I want to restart the timer in the winning and losing condition.

That the winning and losing condition is in a different component and the timer functionality is in a different component.

Nor winingcondition.js is parent to timer.js, Nor timer.js is parent to winingconditon.js

timer.js

```
import { CountdownCircleTimer } from "react-countdown-circle-timer";
const renderTime = ({ remainingTime }) => {
    if (remainingTime === 0) {
        return <div className="timer">Too lale...</div>;
    }

    return (
        <div className="timer font-family flex flex--column align__items--center">
            <div className="value font-size--80 font text--white ">
                {remainingTime}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
const CountDownTimer = (props) => {
    console.log("test");
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="timer-wrapper flex justify__content--center bg-grad--timer b-radius--circle">
                <CountdownCircleTimer
                    isPlaying
                    duration={30}
                    stroke={"white"}
                    colors={["#FFAD22", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF;", "#A30000"]}
                    colorsTime={[25, 20, 15, 0]}
                    onComplete={() => {
                
                        return { shouldRepeat: true, delay: 0 };
                    }}
                    onUpdate={() => {}}
                >
                    {renderTime}
                </CountdownCircleTimer>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CountDownTimer;
```

winingcondition.js

```
    const checkValidation = (isValidation, userAnswer) => {
        
        if (isValidation) {
            props.handleWinFunc();
            Swal.fire({
                title: "Good job!",
                icon: "success",
                timer: 1000,
                showConfirmButton: false,
                backdrop: `
                    rgba(0,0,123,0.4)
                    url("https://acegif.com/wp-content/gif/confetti-12.gif")
                    top
                    no-repeat `,
            });
        } else {
            props.handleWinFunc();
            Swal.fire({
                title: "Wrong Answer",
                html: `<b>Correct answer:${correctAns}</b>`,
                icon: "error",
            });
        }
        setarrayValue([]);
    };
```

Comment: you could use a state management library , a small like zustand or recoil, then store an element called 'key'. Then update 'key' on winning or loosing, wich will restart the timeer if you pass this key as a prop to it. let me know if you need more help

Comment: this could help also : https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-bogdan-qd35m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways.

1. Using `forwardRef` and `useImperativeHandle`
   You can wrap the Component that you want to access with `forwardRef` and define `useImperativeHandle`

```js
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle
};

const TestComponent = forwardRef((variables, ref) => {

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({

    customFunc() {
      // do what you want here: you can return value 
      // or call function inside of the TestComponent
    }
  }))

  return <div > Hello < /div>;

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and from another component,

```js
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const AnotherComponent = () => {
  const compRef = useRef();


  return <div role="none" onClick={() => {
  // this func() will be replaced the function that you defined in the
  // useImperativeHandle from the TEstComponent
  compRef.func()
  }}>
    <TestComponent ref={compRef} />
  </div>
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

2. Using `React.useEffect` and `React.State`
   You can update the state from the Parent Component and pass that state variable to the component that you want to receive.

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from 'react';

// Parent Component 
const ParentComponent = () => {
  // better to use object due to refresh the variable
  const [state, setState] = useState(null);




  return <div role="none" onClick={() => {
    // if you click the parent component it will update state
    // and when the state is updated, then the Child Component will 
    // receive the update from the useEffect
    setState({update: 'update'});
  }}> 
          <ChildrenComponent update={state} /> 
         </div>;

}

const ChildComponent = ({update}) => {

useEffect(() => {
// this will be called whenever the update object is changed
// so you can put something here to update the Child Component's state
}, [update])

return <div>Child</div>

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am doing it by using  React. State